# Restlet Android client - How to map JSON response from ASP.NET Web API to my Java Objects

Tags: java, android, rest, asp.net-web-api, restlet

I'm kinda having trouble understand how to make the best and map my JASON response from an ASP.NET Web API server into my Java classes.

I use this code to request the server data.

```
ClientResource res = new ClientResource(ADDRESS_URL + "/exed/students/");
               Representation rep = res.get();
               try {
                   Log.d(TAG, rep.getText());
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
               }
```

I successfuly can retrieve this JSON representation.

```
{"$id":"1","StudentId":1,"RowVersion":"AAAAAAAAB9M=","User":{"$id":"2","UserId":1,"Username":"1","Password":"1","UserTypeId":1,"FirstName":"George","LastName":"Taskos","RowVersion":"AAAAAAAAB9I=","Student":{"$ref":"1"},"Teacher":null,"UserType":null}}
```

Now I have these Java classes.

The User.

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    // Private fields
    //
    private int userId;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private int userTypeId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userType;
    private Timestamp rowVersion;

    // Setters
    // Getters....
 }
```

And the Student.

```
public class Student extends User implements Serializable {

    // Private fields
    private List<ClassType> classes;
    private List<ExamTaken> examsTaken;
    private Timestamp rowVersionStudent;
}
```

How to retrieve the representation into my objects. I've seen so much and I think I'm so dizzy right now to get a solution.
I'm not familiar with Java server side or anything so I guess thats why I get frustrated about stuff I read on the tutorials and I think lots of stuff missing from the site, or not clearly explained.

Any simple example at least on get the values out and get them into my object like I do with SQLite cursors. 
Deserialization from response would be really great too :)

[EDIT]

After Raw suggestion I ended up with this code.

```
ClientResource res = new ClientResource(ADDRESS_URL + "/exed/students/");
               Representation rep = res.get();

               try {
                   JSONObject response = new JSONObject(rep.getText());
                   Log.d(TAG, rep.getText());
                   JSONObject user = response.getJSONObject("User");
                   Log.d(TAG, "User: " + user.toString());
                   JSONObject student = response.getJSONObject("Student");
                   Log.d(TAG, "Student: " + student.toString());

                   Log.d(TAG, "FirstName: " + user.getString("FirstName"));
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
               }
```

But getting an Exception with this message: Exception: println needs a message

Stacktrace prints this:  Exception: android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)

and the unhandled exception is this:

```
03-06 13:07:14.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25353): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13908
        java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:155)
        at com.tech.ed.data.access.WebServiceRepository$1.run(WebServiceRepository.java:74)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I don't exactly understand what it means!

Thank you.

Comment: Use response.toString() instead of rep.getText(), that may not actually return a string. E.g. textedit.getText() is not a string, you need to do textedit.getText().toString(). If rep.getText() is not a string you will have a null at that line of the Log.d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just have a series of JSONObjects and strings. Just make one JSONObject for the entire results

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(representation);
```

then extract out the user and student objects

```
JSONObject user = response.getJSONObject("User");
JSONObject student = response.getJSONObject("Student");
```

Then you can get any nested strings, ints or whatever from the corresponding objects with something like

```
String firstName = user.getString("FirstName");
```

Comment: Check my edited question, added some feedback to this approach! Thank you so far.

Comment: You are getting an exception because you are using println - i.e. Log.d - in a situation where the string to be logged is null. Try changing rep.getText() to response.toString(). Also you could add conditionals to see where you are not getting a string to log - for example if(response != null){ Log.d("Response", response.toString())

Comment: Thanx, I made it work, there was a thing with the server too.